# How do I set the "elm-format" path within VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, elm

How do I set the *"elm-format"* path within *VSCode*?

I receive the following error:

[image]

I then installed the executable:

[image]

How do I now point *VSCode* to the *elm-format.exe* path as the error suggests?

Do I add it to the *Language Specific Settings* for *Elm* below?

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "elm.formatOnSave": true,
    "[elm]": {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elm-format mechanism is pretty rudimentary, and works as follows:

1) install elm-format for your platform (from github, as you've indicated)

2) add it to your PATH environment variable (i.e. PATH environment variable of the operating system, nothing to do w/ VS Code, etc). The idea is that if you open a command prompt/shell and type `elm-format` the system should be able to find it

3) set `elm.formatOnSave` in VS Code (as you've already done)

Now when VS Code saves, if you've installed, say, the elm extension, it'll invoke the elm-format command line utility (installed in 1 above)

Comment: Better yet if your requirements allow for it, use npm; see [here](https://github.com/avh4/elm-format#installation-). It will set path, etc. If you go this route, remove the EXE and PATH edits described in the answer above.

Comment: I've followed the steps for installing via npm globally but using nodist and everything works fine at the command line but VSCode still can't find it.

Comment: Another common source of problem is if you have multiple node versions installed. I could launch elm-format from the terminal, even from the terminal inside VSCode, but it was installed under /usr/local/Cellar/node/11.6.0, while my PATH was pointing to an earlier version: 10.3.0.
So double check your path, and see if elm-format is under that version's bin directory. Restart VSCode and it should work